# How to run protractor on docker?

Tags: docker, protractor, docker-compose, docker-network, gulp-protractor

I'm a newb with docker & protractor so please bear with me.

I have an app that uses python and django for its backend API, and angular.js for its frontend and e2e test with protractor. So this is how I think I should proceed:

1. I must set a docker container for my **backend** which is in Python-Django, then expose this API through some PORT.
2. Create another container (or a layer not sure which) for the angular.js **frontend**.
3. Download an image for protractor and build the container.
4. Connect all of this containers layer through docker network?

#### Alternative

1. Run backend on local machine.
2. Create docker container for protractor and somehow point the e2e test to the container?

Please help me review the steps to achieve this. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8bDQPVenHQ) gives some insight but not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial idea is just about right.  When setting this up, I typically use a docker-compose file like so...

```
#docker-compose.yml
version: '2'

services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    command: <your django startup command>
  db:
    image: <postgres or whatever>
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    command: <npm start or equivalent>
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Then, I would run my tests with

```
docker-compose run --rm frontend <MY TESTING COMMAND HERE>
```

Docker-compose handles the docker networking stuff for you- in that case your frontend would be able to access your backend at http://backend:.  Protractor and npm and all that fun stuff is installed in your frontend container.

The one major pain point that you haven't thought of yet is that protractor requires a display to work- it won't work with a headless browser like phantomjs, which your docker containers will usually not provide.  This repo is an example of how to install a real browser and provide it a fake display so that it will work in a container... https://github.com/mark-adams/docker-chromium-xvfb, basically replace the chrome startup script with a shell script that starts an xvfb interface and attaches the browser to it.

Comment: For the browser part, I would recommend using Selenium docker images. You can either spin up a complete hub or just standalone headless chrome or firefox. If you need visual access to the browser, the -debug version of images have the VNC enabled https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/.

Comment: thanks paul I think this is a good starting point will use as a guide

Comment: There's a lot of benefits to having protractor run inside your NPM development container- I would use the Selenium image dockerfiles as a guide on how to get it working, but still combine it with my npm image.

Comment: Any useful tutorial or step by step to run protractor tests of an angular 2/4 application from scratch with docker-compose?